# If $f(x)=ax^4+3bx^2-9x+12$ is divisible by $x^2-2x+1$, what is the value of $a+b$?

Tags: polynomials

> If $f(x)=ax^4+3bx^2-9x+12$  is divisible by $x^2-2x+1$, what is the value of $a+b$:

A) $4$

B) $8$

C) $9$

D) $12$

E) $15$

My try:

$x^2-2x+1 =(x-1)^2  \to f(1)=0$. Therefore   $a+3b =-3$.

What should I do now?

Comment: $f(1)=f'(1)=0$.

Comment: You can see that $f(x)=(ax^2+cx+12)(x^2-2x+1)$ by divisibility condition. From here comparing $x$ coefficient gives $c=15$, and because $f$ doesn't have $x^3$ term one can deduce $c-2a=0$, so $a=15/2$. From here you can compute $b$ in the same way, or you can use what you showed ($a+3b=-3$) to compute $b=-7/2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: As $x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2,$

write $$x-1=y\iff x=y+1$$

Answer (score 1):

This means the order of multiplicity of $x=1$ as a  root of $f(x)$ is at least $2$. The differential criterion this is 
$$ f(1)=f'(1)=0\iff \begin{cases}a+3b=-3,
\\4a+6b=9.\end{cases} $$
Set $S=a+b$ and rewrite this linear system as
\begin{cases}S+2b=-3,
\\4S+2b=9, \end{cases}
which shouldn't be too hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=ax^4+3bx^2-9x+12$ is divisible by $(x-1)^2$ means that

$f(1)=0\to a+3 b+3=0$

and $f(x)=(x-1)q(x)$ where $q(x)=a x^3+a x^2+x (a+3 b)+a+3 b-9$ is the quotient of $f(x)/(x-1)$

being divisible by $(x-1)(x-1)$ means that also $q(1)=0\to -9 + 4 a + 6 b=0$

Solve the system $a+3 b+3=0;\;-9 + 4 a + 6 b=0$

from the first equation we get $a=-3b-3$ and we plug this in the second

$-9 + 4 (-3b-3) + 6 b=0 \to b=-\dfrac{7}{2}$ and then $a=\dfrac{15}{2}$

So we can write $f(x)=\dfrac{3}{2} (x-1)^2 \left(5 x^2+10 x+8\right)$